# Standalone project shows empty after initialization

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Well, this is not a question and I don't know if this is against the rules. But I found no topic on this point and I figured out one potential method.

Yesterday, I try to create a standalone vue project with .net6. I read the [official guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-vue?view=vs-2022) and installed node.js,npm,vue,vue@cli and so on. I was pretty sure all the prerequisites were met.
But the project turned out to be empty after initialization by vs2022 with a command window that runs successfully. I tried to reinstall node.js because the project file shows information below:
[sampleproject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0M8t.png)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.4.0-alpha">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>...</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartupCommand>npm run serve</StartupCommand>
    <JavaScriptTestRoot>.\</JavaScriptTestRoot>
    <JavaScriptTestFramework>Jest</JavaScriptTestFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Script Include="**" Exclude="*.esproj;**\node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- This target is copied from the ASP.NET SPA template in order to ensure node_modules are in place. -->
  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Then I found that all needed files were ready in the target files[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zCuR.png)
Anyway, the point is vs2022 language. I changed back my vs2022 language to English by uninstall other languages pack in vs installer. And all files comes out in the project.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwdiS.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJOuG.png)

Everything works well now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as it is, this isn't a question. You're allowed, and even encouraged, to answer your own questions however. If you can formulate this as a question and provide a separate answer to it, it should be fine.

Comment: It saved me! I've just installed VS2022 and I was about to throw it away. Thank you